# Trying to install a freshly built RPM but it says it is dependent on a lib it should not be dependent on

Tags: samba, rpm

The package in question is samba-3.6.7. I've built the package successfully, but when trying to install it, it returns,

```
error: failed dependencies:
libtalloc.so.1 is needed by samba-3.6.7
```

I have no clue why this happens. `libtalloc.so.1` is provided by my current samba package (which I am replacing), but this new samba provides `libtalloc.so` and `libtalloc.so.2`. Why is it still dependent on `libtalloc.so.1` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your RPMs using `mock`. This builds within a chroot containing only the necessary packages for building the RPM and helps to prevent situations like this.

Comment: And as an added bonus, it'll help you find build requirements you missed.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the spec file and remove the requires entry for libtalloc.so.1. Rebuild and it should work. Having those metadata entries incorrect can be rather hard to track down.

Comment: I actually fixed the error by forcing the rpm upgrade, and then rebuilding the rpm. Now, when I remove the rpm and reinstall it using the new rpm, it no longer complains about libtalloc.so.1.

There was no requires entry for libtalloc.so.1 in the spec file, which is why I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

`libtalloc.so.1` was added by the automatic dependency generator which isn't infallible.

Another possibility is that something in your build actually linked against `libtalloc.so.1`  which is why build environments are important.

Assuming the automatic dependency generator is failing and you want to fix it you do so by overriding `__perl_requires` (depending on version of rpm) in your spec file:

```
source1: %{name}-filter-requires.sh
%define __perl_requires %{SOURCE1}
```

Then `%{name}-filter-requires.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/lib/rpm/perl.req $* |\
  sed -e '/libtalloc.so.1/d'
```